# Forgot password multibit

Tags: wallet, multibit, wallet-security

this is two weeks

I am trying to crack my MultiBit portfolio, I do not remember my password recorded in July; I have no old file save my wallet, the word must be no more than 15 characters and must be single and I need only 2-3 characters to remind me.

I looked all over the web and bitcoin forums looking for a solution, but being French, the English pages are poorly translated and difficult to understand. My English is not very strong. I asked walletrecoveryservives, but he couldn't figure out my password using the ideas that I gave him.

I have no more ideas; is the island cracker possible without ideas? Could you help me do it if it's possible?

Comment: What do you mean by `island cracker`?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to partially break a passphrase to get you some characters that could remind you. Depending on the algorithm and what character set was used this could take anywhere from months to centuries.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about bitcoin, but about password recovery, a much broader category and not exclusive to bitcoin.